# Is there any way to make ConstraintLayout take 75% of the width screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

**First attempt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75">
    
    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Second attempt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75">

        ...

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see in the first attempt the attributes have no effect, In the second attempt it is working as I want, But is there any way to make ConstraintLayout take 75% of the width screen without creating 2 of ConstraintLayout?

I can do it programmatically but I want to do it inside XML

Comment: i don't think it will work on root layout because there isn't a parent `ConstraintLayout` against which u are setting the Constraints so u have to do it programmatically at runtime .

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with a `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline`. Set the Guideline to 75% of the parent view and fill it with the constraint layout (match parent).

Comment: But I'm trying to do something like the first attempt